# using a service in the view with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I want to share data between a view and a controller so I create a service. I tried to use the service in the view to set the data but it's not working. I think the problem is this line of code

```
<a .... ng-click="myService.setData('someString')">
```

Comment: Try defining a function in the controller that consumes the service.  Then bind the HTML to the _controller_ function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller you can include the service and then do something like:

```
$scope.myService = $myService;
```

Or better:

```
$scope.setData = function(data) {
  $myService.setData(data);
}
```

And change your html by:

```
<a .... ng-click="setData('someString')">
```